# Do uppercase letters mean anything special in Mathematical Reasoning problems?

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus, convention

I have been asked to determine whether the following is a tautology or not:

> $((p \wedge q) \wedge \sim P)) \rightarrow P $

I am confused whether the uppercase 'P' is just a misprint or it actually means something in this context. Almost 20% of the questions in the question set use uppercase letters while the majority doesn't. I do not have the answer set available to myself right now and googling this was not much help either.

Please clarify this for me.

Comment: Supposing $\sim$ means **not** it is pretty obvious that it cannot be a misprint (by which you probably mean $P$ should be $p$). In general, lower/uppercase in mathematical reasoning does not mean anything special.

Comment: An uppercase P and a lowercase p maybe used to denote two different statements. The statement $((p \wedge q) \wedge \sim P)) \rightarrow P$ is clearly not a tautology (This implication is "false" when p is true, q is true, P is false) assuming that p and P can be different statements. However, if this is a misprint and p and P are same, then the implication will always be true since the hypothesis statement is always false and so, $((p \wedge q) \wedge \sim P)) \rightarrow P$ would be a tautology.

Comment: If you get the answer key to this question which suggests it's a tautology then the question could be a misprint. Also, I don't think uppercase letters have any special meaning here other than denoting mathematical statements.

Comment: "I have been asked to determine whether the following is a tautology or not...." Maybe you should ask the person who asked you to make this determination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lowercase letters are typically used for propositional variables, i.e. symbols representing atomic statements, which always have the concrete truth table given, whereas uppercase letters may be used for formula schemata, i.e. placeholders for arbitrarily complex formulas, which may have special properties in their truh value distribution. For instance, while $P \lor Q$ is in the general case a contingent statement, it may have tautological instances, such as $P = p$ and $Q = \sim p$, where the rows where neither of $P$ and $Q$ are true can not actually exist for this instance. If that is the meaning of the uppercase symbols,  you have to think about whether particular instances make a difference to the tautologicity.